# MySQL index order

Tags: mysql, indexing

I'm just getting into indexes on MySQL using InnoDB.

Firstly, and hopefully I am right, because I am using InnoDB and creating foreign keys, they will automatically be used as an index when querying the table? Is that correct?

Also, I'm reading that the order of the index will effect the speed of a query and even if it is used.

SO...how exactly do I specify the order of the index if that will indeed impact queries.

If you take my below table for example. It would be very beneficial for a query on this table to first use the index FK on org_id, since that is going greatly reduce the amount of rows read, and it is the org_id that most data is going to be separated by in the application.

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `completed_checks` (
  `complete_check_id`   int(15) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `check_type`          varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `check_desc`          varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `assigned_user`       int(12) DEFAULT NULL,
  `assigned_area`       int(12) DEFAULT NULL,
  `org_id`              varchar(8) NOT NULL,
  `check_notes`         varchar(300) DEFAULT NULL,
  `due`                 date NOT NULL,
  `completed_by`        int(12) DEFAULT NULL,
  `completed_on`        datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `status`              int(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `passed`              int(1) DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`complete_check_id`),
  KEY `fk_org_id_CCheck` (`org_id`),
  KEY `fk_user_id_CCheck` (`assigned_user`),
  KEY `fk_AreaID_CCheck` (`assigned_area`)   
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

So would MySQL use the FK index on org_id first when querying this table with org_id in the where clause?

And on a separate note, how would I specify the order in which the indexes are used in MySQL? If this is something that I need to be concerned about?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, foreign keys work as an index. No, the index order is not important, mysql choses the best one. The only special key is the primary key, it defines the physical data structure, but other than that, every index is created equal. Try using `explain` infront of your queries to see which indexes it can and will use. It depends on your query if an index is usable. `select * from completed_checks where org_id = 1` will indeed use `fk_org_id_CCheck`. One addition thing: mysql can only use one key per subquery (basically: per line in your `explain`-result).

Comment: No, foreign keys do not work as an index, MySQL creates an index or use an existing one. No, MySQL does not always choose the best index. MySQL can use 1 index per table.

Comment: Show us a query; we can discuss the 'best' index for that query.  [_My indexing cookbook_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes, this is correct, see MySQL documentation on [creating foreign keys](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html):

> index_name represents a foreign key ID. The index_name value is ignored if there is already an explicitly defined index on the child table that can support the foreign key. Otherwise, MySQL implicitly creates a foreign key index

2. The order of the indexes in a table does not affect what index a query will use. You cannot even say that in general all queries should use such index first since different queries may need different indexes. Moreover, MySQL cannot use more than 1 index per table in a query.
3. In general MySQL decides which index to use (if any). If you believe that MySQL erred in its decision, then you can use [index hint](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/index-hints.html) to influence MySQL's decision:

> Index hints give the optimizer information about how to choose indexes during query processing.

In the newer versions of MySQL you can also use [optimizer hints](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/optimizer-hints.html) to influence the query plan.

The last way to influence index use is to force the update of the index statistics collected on a table using the [analyse table command](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/analyze-table.html):

> ANALYZE TABLE analyzes and stores the key distribution for a table.